# PHP - SQL Search by day(Monday) in php while having datetime field in SQL

Tags: php, datetime, search, weekday

In SQL I have a field 'myDate' with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

In PHP page I have search field that input WEEKDAY only and I want to show all the data from that day only.

For Example:

Search: **Monday**

```
Date                 mydata
---------- -------  ------
2014-10-27 16:44:26  123
2015-11-05 09:20:55   45
2015-11-12 10:00:27  234
2015-11-19 22:38:45  678
```

Please reply with php code or SQL query only. Tq :)

Comment: only weekday? which week will you consider for converting weekday to date ?

Comment: select weekday('2015-10-12'); // it will return 0 and o means Monday in mysql function

Comment: You can refer following link for more information : http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php

Comment: @SumitPandey I mean when I search Monday. All data I had in Monday will show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as it appears from your example dates you want every row where `myDate` is, for example a Monday, then you can use the SQL `WEEKDAY()` function like this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE WEEKDAY(myDate) = 0
```

So if in PHP you have

```
<?php 
    $days = array( 'monday' => 0 , 'tuesday' => 1,
                   'wednesday' => 2 , 'thursday' => 3,
                   'friday' => 4 , 'saturday' => 5,
                   'sunday' => 6 );

    $day = 'Monday';

    $day_code = $days[strtolower($day)];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE WEEKDAY(myDate) = $day_code";
```

Comment: Awesome.. It works, your answer is the best that I got. Thx a lot @RiggsFolly